# MySql order by COUNT and list the total count

Tags: mysql

I am using this code to count and sort from my database:

```
$qry = "select entertainer, count(*) from final_results group by entertainer order by count(*) desc";
```

I get the right result, in as much as it lists all the contents in order or popularity.

What I would like is the top 5 results to display, with a count for each of them and then a total count of all the results.

e.g.

> Top response (10) 
>   Second response (8) 
>   Third response (6) 
>   etc... 
>   Total count = 56

I would appreciate any help and advice.

Thanks,

John C

Comment: Do you want the total count of the 5 top results or from all the results?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the totaly using [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html), but that won't work well with the [`LIMIT 5`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) you want in order to only fetch the top five results. *(Edit:)* It will also not work with the ordering, as discussed in the comments.

So you'll either have to fetch all results, not just the top 5, and sort them in the application, or use two distinct queries, possibly merged on the server side using `UNION` the way @RedFilter suggests. But if you do two separate queries, the I personally would rather issue each one separately from the client application, as splitting the total from the top five later on is too much work for little gain.

To fetch all results, you'd use

```
select entertainer, count(*)
from final_results
group by entertainer with rollup
```

To do two distinct fetches you'd use

```
select entertainer, count(*)
from final_results
group by entertainer
order by count(*) desc
limit 5
```

and

```
select count(*)
from final_results
```

If you want both in a single union, you can do this as

```
(select 1 as unionPart, entertainer, count(*) as count
 from final_results
 group by entertainer
 order by count(*) desc
 limit 5)
union all
(select 2 as unionPart, 'Total count', count(*) as count
 from final_results)
order by unionPart asc, count desc
```

Comment: When using the first select code, I get an error: Error in executing select entertainer, count(*) from final_results group by entertainer with rollup order by count(*) desc query
error:1221 Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY

Comment: You are right, I forgot that `ROLLUP` and `ORDER BY` are mutually exclusive. In some cases the ordering feature of `GROUP BY` can solve this, but here I see no such solution.

Comment: When using the second and third codes, I get the normal result with the first code only but if I use them within the same SELECT I get an error: Error in executing select entertainer, count(*) from final_results group by entertainer order by count(*) desc limit 5 select count(*) from final_results query
error:1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select count(*) from final_results' at line 1. If I use then seperately I get no results displayed.

Comment: @user1535808, second and third example aren't intended to be used directly in a single select. I added an example for the union case as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
select entertainer, count
from (
    (select entertainer, count(*) as count, 1 as sort
    from final_results 
    group by entertainer 
    order by count(*) desc
    limit 5)

    union all 

    (select 'Total count', (select count(*) from final_results), 2 as sort)
) a 
order by sort, count desc
```

Comment: What is the point of the union here? I would have believed an `union all` to preserve the order from the individual queries, so there should be no need for a subsequent sorting. I'm also a bit mystified about this `top 5`, I believe that this isn't MySQL syntax.

Comment: @MvG You are right `LIMIT` is used in MySQL, not `TOP`, I have corrected that. Row order is indeterminate in SQL unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause. Do not rely on order to be preserved with `UNION` alone.

Comment: OK, you are right, the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html) also warn that order is indeterminate. But they also give a syntax which avoids the outer select: `(SELECT …) UNION ALL (SELECT …) ORDER BY`. I guess that would be easier to understand and might be more efficient as well. Want to edit your post in that direction?

Comment: The last subselect for the total count seems superfluous as well to me. Don't take me wrong, it will work, so perhaps I'm overly pedantic in my attempt to get rid of nested selects wherever they aren't really necessary. Tell me if I should stop commenting in this direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I got an error: Error in executing select entertainer, count from (select entertainer, count(*) as count, 1 as sort from final_results group by entertainer order by count(*) desc limit 5 union all select 'Total count', (select count(*) from final_results), 2 as sort ) a order by sort, count desc query
error:1221 Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: @MvG I don't understand your complaints, as your last query is identical to mine.

Comment: In yours I read `select … from ((select …) union all (select … (select …) …)) …` which I wrote as `(select …) union all (select …) …`. So where in your case the select statements nest three deep, in mine they are all directly beneath the outer union. If you look at the [explain output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f0be/5), you'll notice that your query involves two more steps than mine. So I assume mine to be more efficient.

Comment: @MvG Oh, I see. That looks strange to me, it's like there's no `SELECT` clause. But I'll take your word that it's valid in MySQL.